# AngularJS change route by ng-click using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

How can I change the route.state using ng-click instead of a link applying ui-sref.

I've tried this:

```
<button ng-click="selectDir(file.fullPath)">set</button>
```

with

```
$scope.selectDir = function(location) {
    options.storageLocation = location;
    $route.current = 'recorder.options';
}
```

But  it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: ui-sref See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21105057/2539811

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check out the ui-router documentation wiki.

The best solution is to use `$state.go()`. e.g., `$state.go('recorder.options')`

Here's the link to the specific function in the documentation: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

Comment: tyvm, i tried that before . but forgot to inject the $state .. so it didn't work.
Now everythings fine .. thx alot :)

Comment: One way to inject `$state` into all your views is by using `angular.module('myApp').run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) { $rootScope.$state = $state; }]);`.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#note-about-using-state-within-a-template