# AngularJS / ui-router: $state.go does not work inside ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a view where I have the following code:

```
<input type="button" value="New Post" ng-click="$state.go('blog.new-post')">
```

The goal is to transition to a new state without having to use href. Unfortunately the code above just does not fire.

I also tried to include $state in the controller for this view:

```
app.controller('blogPostsController', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $state) ...
```

But still nothing. transictionTo also does not seem to work.

Anyone has any idea on how to make this work?

EDIT: I could only make it work by assigning:

```
$scope.$state = $state;
```

inside my controller. This seems ugly. There is really no other way to access $state without assigning it to scope?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#note-about-using-state-within-a-template you can add it to `$rootScope`, so it will be available in all the scopes and hence all the templates, by

```
angular.module("myApp").run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
});
```

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to add properties like this to the $rootScope.

Comment: In a situation where you really need something like this (this situation doesn't require it - see my answer), a better option is to create a lightweight directive that takes in an attribute value and $parses it in the context of the dependency.

Answer (score 47):

If you are using `ui-router` there is an attribute called `ui-sref` that can be used as follows:

```
<a ui-sref="blog.new-post"></a>
```

I recommend using that and styling the link as a button (can easily be done if you're using a CSS library like Twitter Bootstrap). Then you don't need to mess around with any JavaScript when writing your links.

If you need to pass a parameter into the state, you can do the following:

```
<a ui-sref="blog.edit-post({id: item.id})"></a>
```

where $scope.item is an object with an ID property you want to be passed as a URL parameter.

Comment: methinks this should be the accepted answer.. of course, you won't be able to pass params to the state this way.

Comment: Thanks - this makes it really nice.. one of the things I've also realized is that you can alter part of a url path very elegantly - ie: essentially by navigating within the state.

Example: You have a URL for a state `S` like so: `/foo/:aa/:bb/:cc`


If you're already in that state with a path like `/foo/joe/blow/rocks` and you want to change `blow` to `sixpack` but leave the rest alone, it's just a matter of having `ui-sref="S({bb: 'sixpack'})"` - without worrying about the other params.


This would be harder if you tried to modify `$location.path` directly

Comment: clean, short, simple, and sweet.

Comment: Excellent solution. The only problem I have with it is pairing with an input form. The user won't be able to simply hit enter after they've entered content into the form.

Comment: @jami0821 so you want to have a form navigate to a specific state onsubmit? Since you're probably doing some other onsubmit handling, you can just put `$state.go()` within that `ng-submit` function. If you really want to try this without doing anything in the controller, the following MIGHT work - `<button type="submit" ui-sref="toState">Submit</button>`

Comment: I also use ui-sref; the only problem is that while using ng-click, the class "activated" gets automatically added to the element when user is clicking, so I can add hover styles. Using ui-sref this doesn't happen.
Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Do you know how to use this solution on a tr tag for example?

Comment: @RomainVincent You can do `<tr ui-sref="...` but it's not a good idea to do that. Instead, put an `<a>` tag inside each `<td>` inside your `<tr>`. Use CSS to make sure each link takes up all available space within each `<td>`.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot dynamically change ui-sref value if you wanted (I need it for example). Such as ui-sref="my-ng-repeat-value". It will keep the first, old value. Otherwise this works yeah.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest Solution is to use $Window Service and old Approach**

1. Inject *$window* service of angular JS.
2. Use *history.back()* function of javascript.
3. Done,It is simplest solution if you just want to go back.

*I will not write whole angular JS. Only code that matters:*

**HTML-Code**

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

**JS-Code**

`self.goBack = function(){
      $window.history.back();
    };`