# How to navigate to different pages using ui-route with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, button, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click

I have used tabs and routed pages with ui-router, now i have changed the layout and having buttons in the side navigation panel to route to different pages on button click. No idea how to go after trying so many examples.

I need to navigate to dashboards.html when user clicks Dashboard from navigation menu.

Here is my code:

```
<md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">       
      <md-list>
      <md-item ng-repeat="item in menu">
        <a>
          <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
            <div class="inset">
               <ng-md-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"  ></ng-md-icon>
               <md-tooltip   md-direction="right">{{item.title}}</md-tooltip>
            </div>            
           </md-item-content>
           <md-divider></md-divider>
        </a>
      </md-item>
      <md-divider></md-divider>
     <md-item ng-repeat="item in admin">
        <a>
          <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
            <div class="inset">
              <ng-md-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></ng-md-icon>
               <md-tooltip   md-direction="right">{{item.title}}</md-tooltip>
            </div>
          </md-item-content>
        </a>
      </md-item>
    </md-list>
</md-sidenav>
```

Here is the [`Plnker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/3bcZBYOJTv9CH5V43gH6?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ui-sref="stateName()"` or `ui-sref="stateName({param: 'value'})"` by creating href on HTML, It seems like you need to add states to your `app.config` (configuration phase), below is the example you can refer

**NOTE**

> `ui-sref` never work on button because it does create href tag
>   dynamically and href attribute with url, this won't work on button element, so i'd suggest
>   you to wrap button inside anchor(`<a></a>`) tag

**Example**

```
$stateProvider
.state("stateName": {
  url: "/stateName/:id",
  template: "/test.html",
  controller: 'testCtrl'
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a ui-sref="stateName({id: 1})">
    <button type="button">
</a>
```

This will dynamically create href tag like ``

```
<a  ng-href="#/stateName/1">
    <button type="button">
</a>
```

Reference [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19362082/2435473)

**Update**

Other work around would be you need to write ng-click event and from ng-click function you could to redirect on any route using `$state.go('stateName')`,

You need to change you html menu code like below. basically I've added `ng-click="$parent.navigate(item.icon)"` & Do add new method in controller navigate that will to `$state.go(stateName)`

**Markup**

```
 <md-item ng-repeat="item in menu">
    <a>
      <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center" 
        ng-click="$parent.navigate(item.icon)">
        <div class="inset">
           <ng-md-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"  ></ng-md-icon>
           <md-tooltip   md-direction="right">{{item.title}}</md-tooltip>
        </div>

      </md-item-content>
       <md-divider></md-divider>
    </a>
  </md-item>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.navigate = function(routeName){
  $state.go(routeName)
};
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YAYxQrY5pWwPa0YSHo9W?p=preview)

Comment: can you do that change on plunker

Comment: its already working, you need to drag the screen to see the navigation panel

Comment: when you would be able to?

Comment: @Sajeetharan did you checked my answer?

Comment: ya bro , am getting <!-- uiView: undefined --> after routing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74262/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-pankajparkar).

Comment: ya bro working! undefined was because controller was not there. thanks